# Is there a way to switch Webdriver to a new session that opens a new window and closes the parent window automatically?

Tags: internet-explorer, switch-statement, window

I have a test case that requires me to use IE. When I enter the url, it navigate me to a new session window where I am authorized by my lanID and closes the parent window automatically. So I am not able to switch to the new opened window.

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the driver.Quit method to close the parent window, then create a new InternetExplorerDriver instance to open the child window. By using this method, it seems that there is no need to switch windows. If I misunderstand your problem, please let me know freely.

The difference between the driver.Quit and driver.Close methods as below:

The **driver.close()** command is used to close the current browser window having focus. In case there is only one browser open then calling driver.close() quits the whole browser session.

The **driver.quit()** command which calls the driver.dispose method, it will turn closes all the browser windows and terminates the WebDriver session. If we do not use quit() at the end of the program, the WebDriver session will not be closed properly.

Please check the following sample:

```
    private const string URL = @"https://dillion132.github.io/login.html";
    private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"D:\Downloads\webdriver\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0";  // where the Selenium IE webdriver EXE is.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InternetExplorerOptions opts = new InternetExplorerOptions() { InitialBrowserUrl = URL, IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true, IgnoreZoomLevel=true };

        //create a webdriver to open parent window. after doing something, close the window.
        using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, opts))
        {
            driver.Navigate(); 

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var txtname = driver.FindElementById("txtname");
            txtname.SendKeys("BBB");

            var txtpass = driver.FindElementById("txtpassword");
            txtpass.SendKeys("123");

            var submit = driver.FindElementById("Submit1");
            submit.Click(); 
            driver.Quit(); 
        }

        InternetExplorerOptions opts2 = new InternetExplorerOptions() { InitialBrowserUrl = "https://www.bing.com", IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true, IgnoreZoomLevel = true };
        //create another window.
        using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, opts2))
        {
            driver.Navigate(); 
            Thread.Sleep(3000); 
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I find out that it is about Internet explorer.  InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);               I handled it like this

Answer (score 0):

InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);

It is about IE. I handled it from IE options. It worked.

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding. ^_^